# Why does copy initializaton require destructor in C++17 with guaranteed move/copy elision?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, copy-elision, copy-initialization

The following code compiles with MSVC (/permissive-) and fails to compile with GCC/Clang for m_ptr1 and m_ptr2.

```
#include <memory>

struct ForwardDeclared;

class A {
    public:
        explicit A();
        ~A();
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<ForwardDeclared> m_ptr1 = nullptr;    // not ok
        std::unique_ptr<ForwardDeclared> m_ptr2 {std::unique_ptr<ForwardDeclared>{}};    // not ok
        std::unique_ptr<ForwardDeclared> m_ptr3 {nullptr};    // ok 
        std::unique_ptr<ForwardDeclared> m_ptr4;              // ok
};

int main() {
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

[Code at compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/58aGYb)

My understanding is that the `=` sign results in [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), however, thanks to [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) I would expect `m_ptr2` would still be initialized without failure.

Why does `m_ptr2` require a destructor of ForwardDeclared and are Clang/GCC correct for this? (Bonus: Is it correct to conclude that m_ptr1 is incorrectly accepted by MSVC?)

**EDIT:** Logged a bug with clang about this issue: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/54291

Comment: Note that making `ForwardDeclared` a complete type [fixes the compilation problem](https://godbolt.org/z/YGPKex).

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko I know, however, that also increases the amount of code that needs to be included

Comment: Maybe [a related bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60497).

Comment: @xskxzr Interesting bug, however, it looks different at first sight. In the first example it uses a customer deletor. This bug is also logged in libstdc++, while MSVC and Clang use a different standard library. (I'm forcing libc++ for clang)

Comment: I rechecked your issue (since my first comment was wrong...) and I do not think, that it's the kind of bug that xskxzr linked here - I still doubt it's a bug at all (happens almost never that clang and gcc are both wrong while MSVC is fine...). I do not fully understand, how godbolt handles incomplete symbols.Is there a hidden setting for that? And did you reproduce this issue with a real project? PS: Isn't m_ptr2 actually direct initialization?

Comment: It doesn't need to link for compiler explorer, I've reproduced this with MSVC and Clang-cl on real code. (This is just a reduced form of it)

Comment: I'm also not sure its a bug in clang, however, I would like to understand it

Comment: Include all your compiler versions.

Comment: @asteroidswithwings I don't think the exact versions are relevant, using the latest available, trunk for GCC and clang and 2019 for MSVC, for the details, see compiler explorer link

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue with clang. Compiles fine for me for several latest compiler versions (as expected). Can you ensure from your compiler output that the instantiation origin is a valid location where the definition of ForwardDeclared is available?

Comment: @JVApen You have no idea whether they're relevant. Always provide them. Help us to help you. And remember that your question lasts forever: what is trunk today may not be trunk tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

[CWG 2426](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2426) refers specifically to a destructor being potentially invoked in the cases:

> A destructor is potentially invoked if it is invoked or as specified in 7.6.2.8 [expr.new], 8.7.4 [stmt.return], 9.4.2 [dcl.init.aggr], 11.9.3 [class.base.init], and 14.2 [except.throw]. A program is ill-formed if a destructor that is potentially invoked is deleted or not accessible from the context of the invocation.

Section [11.9.2 [class.expl.init]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.init#class.expl.init) is not mentioned in the above list, and thus seems not to be in the *destructor is potentially invoked* case.

Which raises a question whether indeed as @Fedor argues, MSVC is wrong and GCC and Clang are correct. On the face of it, it seems to be the opposite.

Note that [cppreference on copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) doesn't argue that all cases of copy elision require the destructor to be visible, it refers only to the case of:

> In a return statement, when the operand is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type [...] The destructor of the type returned must be accessible at the point of the return statement and non-deleted, even though no T object is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've unmarked the question as solved for now and logged a bug with clang about it: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/54291

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that the = sign results in copy initialization, however, thanks to copy elision I would expect m_ptr2 would still be initialized without failure.

Copy elision requires the destructor of the type be accessible and non-deleted, even though no object is destroyed, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

So GCC and Clang correctly check the destructor, which is not valid for the incomplete type `ForwardDeclared`.

> Bonus: Is it correct to conclude that m_ptr1 is incorrectly accepted by MSVC?

Yes, MSVC is incorrect here.

See [Why is public destructor necessary for mandatory RVO in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657541/why-is-public-destructor-necessary-for-mandatory-rvo-in-c/) for an explanation on why mandatory copy-elision doesn't apply.

> Why does m_ptr2 require a destructor of ForwardDeclared and are Clang/GCC correct for this?

The same reasoning applies here about the necessity of valid destructor for the copy elision.

Comment: In the case of a return value the destructor is potentially invoked according to https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/stmt.return#2.sentence-7, but in the rule for copy elision from prvalue initializers of same type I don't see any equivalent requirement: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#general-16.6.1. cppreference also mentions this explicitly in the case of copy elision in return statements.