# Must aggregate field destructor be available for the code creating the aggregate in C++?

Tags: c++, aggregate, language-lawyer, private-members

Please consider the following example with an aggregate `struct B` with the field of type `U`. The field's destructor is private, but available to the aggregate due to `friend` declaration, and not available for calling from `main` function:

```
class U { 
    ~U() {}
    friend struct B;
};

struct B { U v{}; };

int main()
{
    B b; //ok everywhere
    auto pb = new B; //ok everywhere
    delete pb;
    pb = new B{}; //ok in GCC, error in Clang
    delete pb;
}
```

And if one uses aggregate initialization `B{}` then the code is accepted only by GCC, while Clang reports the error:

```
error: temporary of type 'U' has private destructor
    pb = new B{}; //ok in GCC, error in Clang
               ^
<source>:2:5: note: implicitly declared private here
    ~U() {}
    ^
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/c33Gbqfqh

I have not found any mentions of the "destructor" in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization .
Is it really required by the standard for the aggregate field to have its destructor available to every potential user of the aggregate?

Comment: clang 7.1.0 can compile this. clang 8.0.0+ can not.

Comment: I do not understand why this code creates a temporary at all. There is a matching question from yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68672933/why-does-default-initialization-of-a-class-field-in-c-require-destructor-invoc

Comment: Presumably the idea is that if a field constructor throws, then already constructed fields have to be destroyed (and a corner case of 1 field never having to be destroyed in this manner didn't get special handling). Since aggregate init is not a constructor call, it makes some sense that access is cheched for the caller and not for the aggregate.

Comment: Clang rejects `B b{};` too for the same reason. "_temporary of type 'U' has private destructor_"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Access to the destructor is indeed required by the standard. Quoting from N4868 (closest to the published C++20), [[dcl.init.aggr]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.aggr#8) says:

> The destructor for each element of class type is potentially invoked
> from the context where the aggregate initialization occurs. [ Note:
> This provision ensures that destructors can be called for
> fully-constructed subobjects in case an exception is thrown. — end
> note ]

For completeness, [[class.dtor]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.dtor#15) says:

> [...] A program is ill-formed if a destructor that is potentially
> invoked is deleted or not accessible from the context of the
> invocation.

---

[dcl.init.aggr]/8 was added by the resolution of [DR2227](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2227), first published in C++20. It's a defect report, so compilers should apply it to previous standard versions as well.